# How to Send file of any format to Docusign using docusign Api

Tags: java, docusignapi

I have a requirement to attach file of any format and create the Docusign Envelope,currently i am able to attach only pdf files ,
How can i attach file of any format and create the envelope ?.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this via the API? Web app? Do you have a code snippet of you providing the document in your API call and/or error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the DocuSign Website you can upload different types of documents through the file upload button.

If you are using the DocuSign REST API and sending raw API requests and constructing your own JSON you can make a `multipart/form-data` POST request with the appropriate header set based on the file type you are sending.  For instance, if sending a `.docx` file you need to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`.  You can test this through the [API Explorer](http://iodocs.docusign.com/), and here is the [corresponding REST API call](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#Basic%20Scenarios/Creating%20an%20Envelope%20from%20a%20Document.htm%3FTocPath%3DBasic%2520Scenarios%7C_____1).

Lastly, if you are using the open source DocuSign API clients such as the [DocuSign-Java-Client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client) you should be able to simply provide the path to the file you want signed then just set the `fileExtension` property within the `documents` node of your request.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ergin ,I was using through Docusign-java-Client and setting the format in file Extension property solved my problem:).